# How to set GTK icon theme in i3?

Tags: gtk, icons, i3

How to change icon theme in i3? If this matters, I'm working on Arch Linux. I googled, but I can only find info about GTK theme, not icons.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I can think of at least 2 options you can choose from:

### 1. use LXAppearance

[LXAppearance](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/lxappearance/) can change the GTK2/3 icons (and themes, fonts, etc.). LXAppearance is part of the LXDE desktop environment, but as you can see on the package page, its dependencies are only `dbus-glib` and `gtk2`.

I prefer using LXAppearance because it gives access to all important theme-related settings but is still very lightweight.

### 2. Edit config files directly

You can change `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` directly (the former for icons in GTK2 applications, the latter for GTK3 applications) - the setting you're looking for is [gtk-icon-theme-name](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-icon-theme-name) in both cases.

For GTK2, you can just add a line like

```
gtk-icon-theme-name="Faenza-Ambiance"`
```

to the file, for GTK3 the line needs to be inside a `[Settings]` section like

```
[Settings] 
gtk-icon-theme-name=Faenza-Ambiance
```

You can find the name of the theme by looking at the `Name` property inside its `index.theme` file.

Comment: But what variable to set in that files?

Comment: @enedil I've updated myanswer with that information.

Comment: If you are using Gnome along with i3 you can also use the gnome-tweaks app.